# Can you combine the App Engine firewall with IAP? (OR not AND)

Tags: google-app-engine, firewall, google-iap

Is it possible to set up App Engine so that access to the application is granted to a requester that is:
- Either on the App Engine firewall IP address whitelist (ie, with no authentication)
- Or authenticated using Identity-Aware Proxy
?

In other words, so that access is granted to anyone on the corporate network, *or* to anyone logging in from the public Internet?

Answer (score 3):

Not today, but it's on our roadmap.  --Matthew, Google Cloud IAP engineering